# Compatibility TTS issue in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, text-to-speech

As you can see below, Google has created a new set of APIs for TTS. So, apps created using previews implementantions will stop working in ICS:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

The link above says we should look for a blog post with a compatibility layer just in case we need to havesome backwards compatibility.

Does anyone knows how we can implement TTS using the new guidelines WITHOUT breaking backwards compatibility?

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,

Carlos

Answer (score 1):

I use Svox and have noticed that in ics the only default engine seems to be google tts.

I jump back to my gingerbread phone and have svox working fine as the default because the settings allow me to chose pico or svox as the default.

Unfortunately in ics , while you can set the 'preferred tts engine'
In gingerbread by contrast, the settings/voice input & output/text to speech settings can be used to set the default tts engine.

So I end up with certain apps like voice alerts using the svox 'preferred tts' but other programs wount unless it is google tts.

WHY COMPLICATE THIS TO MAKE IT  P R E F F E R E D.  ?

WHY NOT JUST MAKE IT   D E F A U L T and have apps override if we want to....preferred is to vaque.  they had it right in gingerbreat...why go backwards ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement *"So, apps created using previews implementantions will stop working in ICS:"* ( I guess you meant 'previous' not 'previews') is misleading.

My app built with Android 2.2 synthesises speech perfectly well on an API 15 emulator. I would expect it to work just as well on a real device.

There are a couple of ***deprecated*** methods but this just means that these methods ***may*** be removed in a future version, not that they won't work in the current version. It's just a warning that there are newer and better methods now available.

Comment: Hello NickT,  you're right. I meant previous,not previews. What TTS engine are you using? I am using Svox and it crashes

Comment: In the emulator it's just the default PICO engine. My phone is still on 2.3.5 and uses PICO. I won't be getting ICS on the phone till next month but I expect I'll leave it on PICO then too.

Comment: Does anyone here uses Svox? I can share some codes so we can find a solution! I searched for a solution in Google and in SVox pages but I found almost nothing. I wish I can make my app work in Honeycomb and ICS devices.